# How to estimate when a residual chart is indicating error in the regression?

Tags: regression, residuals

I am new to statistics and I understand that when a pattern can be found in the plots of the residuals and variables of a regression this is an indication that there is something which is missing from the regression.

I made a regression with two parameters, X1 and X2, for the regression I used:
X1, X1^2, X2*X2, X2.

From this I got the following plots:
[image]

So far, I think there might be an error with X1^2, because there seems to be a slight curvature in the plot. All the others look fairly spread out around the horizontal axis.

What could I deduce from such plots ?

Here is the Summary for more information:

[image]

Comment: Well, there are few data points so difficult to interpret. I think you may be overinterpreting, I would not be worried just because of this plots.

Comment: Just had a meeting with a statistician at my university today.  And he said the same thing, over interpretation and data points are too clustered.